# Access untransformed xml in chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt

We have a standard xml format emitted by almost every server in our company that is, needless to say, rather hideous. I have an xslt style sheet that makes it much easier to get relevant information out, but due to many factors, it is not practical to deploy the stylesheet linked inside the xml. I am working on a chrome extension to perform the transform on any page that matches a url pattern.

My problem is, when you load the xml document in chrome, the browser tries to be helpful and transforms it into their pretty html format. I can't apply my xslt unless I can access the source xml from my content script. I have tried to fetch the original source from the url and have had issues with permissions in the extension.

My only other idea is to use jquery and manually parse out from their html, but that looks a bit painful, and I already have a valid xsl that does everything I need.

Is there a better way I can get the source xml to transform it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't insert the processing instruction, you can trigger the transformation using JavaScript:

```
function loadXML(fileName,mime) {
  var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttpRequest.open("GET",fileName,false);
  if(mime) xmlHttpRequest.overrideMimeType(mime);
  xmlHttpRequest.send("");
  return xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
}

function transformDocument(url) {
  var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(loadXML('test.xsl','application/xslt+xml'));
  return xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(loadXML(url),document);
}
```

`transformDocument()` would return an HTML element that you can then display.  I see several options:

- Put it into an iframe.
- Replace the current document with the transformed document (e.g. by replacing head and body)
- Grab some div from the transformed document and insert it into the current document.
- Opening it as a data URL.
- ...